# rails page won't display entirely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, aol

I'm having the most peculiar problem, and I was hoping I someone could point me in the right direction on how to address it (or even locate it...).  I'm working on a rails site, and the pages display in most browsers without any issues.  In others (AOL, IE 6 - 7, and some of the other lesser used ones) the page will load, with all of the correct formatting, but completely missing the inside content.

For example, the site uses a traditional online store format, but will load the name of the site, the name of the product, and the page footer, but not the description or images.  This issue has been reproduced on several computers, but I can't figure it out at ALL.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach to this sort of problem would be to use the browser to get the html you are trying to render (in firefox, View>>Page Source), and saving it as a static html file. Then you can fiddle with this file one piece at a time until you figure out what's throwing IE for a loop.

Comment: Thought I'd just update this for anyone who may happen upon it.  I was using grid.cs system for development, and my ID was overriding the class methods they use.  silly issue, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction, dunno why I didn't think of it before ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you view the page source is the data you are looking for included? This can help you figure out if you have a formatting issue on the client side or a data generation issue on the server side.

Comment: just checked, can't believe I didn't think of that in the first place.  it shows all of the content in the source, but not displayed in the browser still.  any ideas?